# Embed an Excel spreadsheet in a Word 2007 document, and reflect the Excel file changes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-word-2007

I know how to embed an existing Excel file `test.xlsx` in a Word 2007 document `test.docx` with:

```
Ribbon > Insert > Object > Browse
```

and then it's inserted in the Word document.

But how to make that, if I close the `test.docx` document, open `test.xlsx`, **do modifications in the Excel file**, and then reopen `test.docx`, the changes are reflected in the Word document?

Comment: Several ways to do this are outlined on [this tutorial page](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/link-excel-worksheet-to-word-doc/).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution: there is a checkbox (probably something like "Link" in English) when embdedding the Excel file:

[image]

Then:

- when you reopen the .docx file after the .xlsx has been modified, a popup asks if you want to refresh the embedded spreadsheet.
- you can also right-click on the embedded spreadsheet at any time and choose *Update...*